# serial data only works with messagebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

In my handler for receiving data over the serial port, when data is received I store it to a string and do a .contains search to determine if something needs to be done with the data. When the application is sitting idle and the (lets call it a modem) sends something like "Connected" it works fine.

The problem is when I poll the machine. When I initiate a command that expects return results It does not work and I cant figure out why. Now If I start the function with a Message Box it will work. I would rather not have an unnecessary Message Box.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        RefreshTextBox d = new RefreshTextBox(RefreshTextBoxResults);
        Invoke(d);
    }
    else
    {
        RefreshTextBoxResults();
    }
}

private void RefreshTextBoxResults()
{
    //MessageBox.Show("refresh text is occurring");
    indata1 = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    rx.AppendText(indata1);

    string dataCheck = indata1.ToUpper();

    //MessageBox.Show(dataCheck);
    if (indata1.ToUpper().Contains("CONNECT"))//dataCheck.Contains("CONNECT"))
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("connect");
        cState.Text = "Connected";
        if(connected==false)
            connectLink();
    }
    if (dataCheck.Contains("CONNECTED"))
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("Active Call in Session");
        cState.Text = "Connected";
        if (connected==false)
            connectLink();
    }
    if (dataCheck.Contains("NO"))
    {
        cState.Text = "Disconnected";
        disconnect();
    }
    if (dataCheck.Contains("CAMPOS"))
    {
        campos = indata1;
        camDat = true;
    }
}

private void cState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    writeDevice("callstatus");
}

public void writeDevice(string cmd)
{
    try
    {
        {
            serialPort1.Write(cmd + "\r\n");
        }
    }
    catch
    { noconnect(); }
}
```

When I execute cstate() it should return the call status and type if any. The modem does respond as I can see it in my prompt box. If the word connected is anywhere in there It should change a label's text to say "Connected". As the code sits, nothing happens to that label. But, if I remove the comment on the first line in RefreshTextBoxResults() making that MessageBox active, it detects the status of the modem.

I just don't see what is going on. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: did you try to put indata1 inside a messagebox and see what it shows?

Comment: Just an observation, the first two if statements: if (indata1.ToUpper().Contains("CONNECT")) and if (dataCheck.Contains("CONNECTED")) are doing the same thing.

Comment: and why are you using lots of ifs you should use if else and else as well...

Comment: MessageBox is blocking, it stops execution while it waits for you to hit "OK". What happens if you do Debug.WriteLine instead?

Comment: Absolutely do not show a message box or other resource intensive tasks in the `DataReceived` event handler. You are only asking for trouble. Better to log the information or use Debug, Trace, or Console if you are just troubleshooting or developing.

Comment: Checking the contents of indata1 shows that it has the correct information. As for the Messageboxes, I definitely don't want want them at all. I put them in there to see if the function was even being executed. Sorta old school debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, if I remove the comment on the first line in RefreshTextBoxResults()

That's the key phrase.  The issue is that you use ReadExisting().  Serial ports are very slow, your DataReceived event handler will typically only get one or two characters.  By displaying the message box, you *slow it down*.  That allows the serial port driver to read *more* characters.  Enough for ReadExisting to read the entire "Connected" string instead of just "C" or "Co".

Hard to diagnose too when you use a debugger, single stepping the code also slows it down enough to allow the port to get enough characters.

What you need to do is process the response *only* after you got the entire response string.  That's always easy with a modem, just use ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting().  You may have to tweak the value of the NewLine property.

Comment: I will have to try that. I am not using a modem exactly but it does share a lot of similar properties.

Comment: This was the golden ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox()` starts a modal dialog message loop, which will allow queued window messages an opportunity to be processed.  It's conceivable that some of the manipulations you're doing to the textbox control in your RefreshTextboxResults() function post messages to the control window handle. If this is the case, the window handle won't receive such messages until execution flow enters or returns to the message loop. That will happen in your function if you  open a modal dialog (like MessageBox).

Not that this is a solution, but it should confirm this theory: try replacing `MessageBox()` with a call to `Application.DoEvents()`.  (Assuming your app is a WinForms app)  If this clears up the blockage to the same degree as calling `MessageBox()`, then it's pretty clear that you have some pending messages piled up in the message queue that need to be dealt with.

Comment: I replaced the MessageBox() with the Application.DoEvents() and it did not give the same result as the MessageBox.

Comment: Ok, then your issue isn't with queued messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to block the application till the data is fully received or you can use background treads to do the job for you.